# systemd timers with long lived processes, avoiding overlaps

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer, systemd-unit

I have script that will scan for tasks, and work on one at a time to completion and then exit. Execution can last 1s (no tasks) to 2hours (heavy task). And subsequent runs should start as soon as possible to check for remaining/incoming work.

I'd like systemd to manage this.

```
[Time]
OnUnitActiveSec=1
Unit=tasker@0.service
```

I'd like for each service to be started every 1s, if not already running. Should `Type=simple` cover this or do I need `Conflicts` with itself? what about `Type=oneshot` with `RemainAfterExit=no`? There's too many options for the service Unit to satisfy this... but they all seem wrong.

bonus: how to correctly log in journal if the process exited with or without errors?